# The "logger" option function in electrion-unhandled threw an error

Tags: windows, electron

This error [The "logger" option function in electrion-unhandled threw an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t89pC.png)
pop up after I open pc second times after I've done cleaning.

Is this something I should worry about? If it is, what's the solution and how to prevent this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.